# String manipulation while parsing CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

The third column of a CSV file is as like this `Every Monday 12am-2am` of a CSV file.

```
ACB;Third Week;Every Monday 12am-2am
XYZ;Third Week;Every Tuesday 8pm-10pm
```

I would like to capture only `12am` and `8pm` and so on until the end of the csv file and write the details to a separate CSV file the complete output, like below.

```
ACB;12am
XYZ;8pm
```

Comment: Please post your code along with any error messages, this is not a code requesting web site.

Answer (score 1):

Use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) extract a modified part of the data. The idea is to use `Select-Object` to select and modify the data like so,

```
select code, @{name="day";expression={ if($_.day -match "\d{1,2}[ap]m") {$Matches[0]} }}
```

So what's going on? The select (shorthand for `Select-Object`) can use a script block as an expression for processing. The argument is a hash table that contains manipulated property's name as a data source and expression that does stuff to it. The part `if($_.day -match "\d{1,2}[ap]m") {$Matches[0]}` checks if the `day` column value matches a regex for 1 or 2 digits followed by am or pm.

As for more complete an example,

```
$data = @'
ACB;Third Week;Every Monday 12am-2am
XYZ;Third Week;Every Tuesday 8pm-10pm
'@
$c = ConvertFrom-Csv -InputObject $data -Delimiter ";" -Header @('code','week','day')
$c | select code, @{name="day";expression={ if($_.day -match "\d{1,2}[ap]m") {$Matches[0]} }}
# Output
code day
---- ---
ACB  12am
XYZ  8pm
```

Comment: Thank you, Is it possible to get content of csv file here instead of hardcoding.     $data = @'
ACB;Third Week;Every Monday 12am-2am
XYZ;Third Week;Every Tuesday 8pm-10pm
'@

Comment: @BUG Sure, use [`Import-CSV`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx) instead of `ConvertFrom-CSV` that I used for the sample.